# Cannot run Ruby Specs from Rubymine

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I am having issues running Rspecs from Rubymine. I can run from terminal and I am using same Ruby SDK on both ends.

RubyMine 2018.1
Build #RM-181.4203.562, built on March 27, 2018

Ruby Version : ruby-2.4.1-ruvy

**Testing started at 17:53 ...
/Users/matspeda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1-ruvy/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/matspeda/dolphin_tests/spec/coach_assignment_spec.rb
Process finished with exit code 0**

I've tried with other ruby versions and I get the same message, no errors at all, it just doesn't run. Not sure what happened since this was previously working. I've tried completely erasing RubyMine & reinstalling but it didn't do the trick. I am on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: What do you type from the command line that runs your tests correctly? Is it your intention to run only the single `coach_assignment_spec.rb` file?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run that single file. If I enter: "rspec spec/coach_assignment_spec.rb" then it runs correctly. Thanks.

Comment: And how are you trying to run the spec file in RubyMine?